# How can you wear Red's Clothes

Tags: terraria-mobile

For Terraria Mobile, how can you wear Red's clothes? Every time I put them on even a mannequin they disappear.

Comment: This clothing appears to be for Expert mode only, which is not available on the Mobile version of the game - so how did you even obtain them? It seems to me that its unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Since Red's Clothes are "Unobtainable" on the Mobile Version of Terraria, there are serious glitches with certain items. Red's Clothes have been known to not be wearable in the Mobile Edition. Either their texture (On Body) or their code is missing/unprogrammed, causing it to be unwearable. Either that or they just added an unusable copy of it to troll hackers/modders/cheaters. Also hacked in items don't always work due to glitches. (No offence, but I know you hacked because Red's Clothes are unobtainable without hacks.)

In a nutshell: You can't wear Red's Clothes on Mobile. You just can't.

Hope this helps! =D